# Multiple User Models Laravel JWT Auth

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

I have to user models in my eloquent:

- User
- OfficeUser

OfficeUser is in defined in the JWT config as standard model. 
Now I have written a Middleware for authenticate each of them

authUser:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    Config::set('auth.providers.users.model', \App\User::class);
    try {

        if (! $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()) {
            return response()->json(['user_not_found'], 404);
        }

    } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException $e) {

        return response()->json(['token_expired'], $e->getStatusCode());

    } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException $e) {

        return response()->json(['token_invalid'], $e->getStatusCode());

    } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException $e) {

        return response()->json(['token_absent'], $e->getStatusCode());

    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

authOfficeUser

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    try {

        if (! $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()) {
            return response()->json(['user_not_found'], 404);
        }

    } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException $e) {

        return response()->json(['token_expired'], $e->getStatusCode());

    } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException $e) {

        return response()->json(['token_invalid'], $e->getStatusCode());

    } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException $e) {

        return response()->json(['token_absent'], $e->getStatusCode());

    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Additionally I have a login function for each of them:

LoginUser

```
if ($user){
        if (Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
            // grab credentials from the request
            $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

            try {
                // attempt to verify the credentials and create a token for the user
                Config::set('auth.providers.users.model', \App\User::class);
                if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
                    return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
                }
            } catch (JWTException $e) {
                // something went wrong whilst attempting to encode the token
                return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
            }
```

LoginOfficeUser

```
if ($user){
        if (Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
            // grab credentials from the request
            $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

            try {
                // attempt to verify the credentials and create a token for the user
                Config::set('auth.providers.users.model', \App\OfficeUser::class);
                if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
                    return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
                }
            } catch (JWTException $e) {
                // something went wrong whilst attempting to encode the token
                return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
            }
```

Unfortunately when I login and try to call a route behind the authUser Middleware I get an "user_not_found"

Does anybody have an idea why this happens?
OfficeUser authentication works fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### **Posting for anyone who finds this questions**

Although it's not recommended to have two user tables, but I had a similar requirement of setting up JWT with one of our clients. This is how I solved the issue.

**No need to make any changes to the providers in `config/auth.php'**

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
           'model' => App\User::class,
     ],

]
```

In your authentication controller, dynamically modify the model used by the providers by setting

`\Config::set('auth.providers.users.model', \App\Trainer::class);`

**Example code**

**In authenticate() method**

```
if ($credentials['user_type'] == 'consultant') {

\Config::set('auth.providers.users.model', \App\Trainer::class);

} else {
    \Config::set('auth.providers.users.model', \App\User::class);
}

//Find the user

//Create the token
if ($user) {
   $customClaims = ['user_type' => $credentials['user_type']];
   $token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user,$customClaims);
} else {
  return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
}
```

You will have to do the same while parsing the token to authenticate the user as well. Example code

**In getAuthenticatedUser() method**

```
$payload = JWTAuth::parseToken()->getPayload();
$user_type = $payload->get('user_type');

if($user_type === 'consultant'){
   \Config::set('auth.providers.users.model', \App\Trainer::class);
}else{
   \Config::set('auth.providers.users.model', \App\User::class);
}

if (!$user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()) {
    return response()->json(['user_not_found'], 404);
}
```

Comment: Ps: You should override the configuration changes in the controller constructor.

Comment: I have done all thing the same like you suggest still JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate() refers to the User model instead of the given model @amal Ajith

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `__construct` function in each of your controllers as follows. So that jwt know which model to authenticate.

**OfficeUserController**

```
function __construct()
{
    Config::set('jwt.user', OfficeUser::class);
    Config::set('auth.providers', ['users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => OfficeUser::class,
        ]]);
}
```